# Wierd behavior with Visual Studio Debugger

Tags: visual-studio-2013, gpu, visual-studio-debugging, directx-11

I experienced some weird behavior with Visual Studio's Debugger when running VS with the Dedicated GPU.

What is weird is that when I terminate the program I am building, the debugger stays on. I don't see this when running VS with the integrated graphics. Also - I checked if there were threads or COM-objects still alive and there is an active thread, but no COM references.

I think it's weird. Have any of you experienced anything like it? Am I missing something obvious? Are there settings to be changed or special rules when running VS with the Dedicated GPU?

It doesn't really hurt anything - but it makes my OCD explode. ;)

Thank you all in advance for your constructive input :D

Most Sincerely
Alpha Silverback

Comment: That would annoy me too.  When I have seen this type of behavior, it is my fault.  (few questions...) When you say 'terminate the execution', how are you specifically doing that?  Are you able to hit the 'break all' (pause button - Ctrl-Alt-Break)?  Do you have the debug flag set (D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG)?  What does the output window say?  Sometimes an assertion will fail, but will not popup the dialog, and will show in the output window.

Comment: I can see how that is a faulty expression. Sorry for that - it's rubbish : I mean I post a quit-message - sending the program to the internal termination functions. :) The device is in debug-mode - yes. I checked that all references are zero and all parameters are nullified before returning from WinMain.  I can tell the debugger is on from the orange frame (_and from the fact that I can't debug before I manually press shift+F5_). Yes - I am able to break all or pause the process. 

Thank you for your reply!

Comment: Oh: and the output window output S_OK or 0x0 (_No errors and everything is ok_).  There's nothing that's not how it should be. :) Except that I have to mmanually stop debugging.

Comment: Got it.  Are you using PostMessage with WM_CLOSE, or PostQuitMessage?

Comment: I use PostQuitMessage( 0 );  Oh. I should mention that this behavior is identical whether I specifically call this function or let the DefWindowProc() catch me pressing the window 'X' . (As in - I don't know how the default window procedure throws the quit-message)

Comment: Ooooh.. I found out that running the program with the dedicated GPU around VS actually fails to kill the thread. The process is still running - The  Task Manager revealed this. So why does the thread not die? Hmmm

Comment: Apparently, there's hidden calls being made. The call-stack pending after everything else has shut down looks like this: > ntdll.dll!_NtWaitForMultipleObjects@20() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!_TppWaiterpThread@4() Unknown
  kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown
  ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8() Unknown

Comment: I think there may be more to this.  It appears that you are deadlocked.  However I am glad you were able to make progress.

Comment: Well I am still investigating what the problem is. Would it be too much to ask you to try and compile a version I know will produce the deadlock? I can ship the VS Solution so that you won't have to do anything else but compile and run with different GPUs. I need fresh eyes!!

Comment: Sure.  Put the zip up on Google drive, dropbox, OneDrive, or other, and I will grab it from your link.

Comment: Thanks. This is the earliest version I have, that produces the error. The program does nothing but show a couple of windows, init a dx11 device and compile simple shaders. Please tell me if you experience the same with either of your GPU's. 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxnLa_qsqQBobU9HME1pMjROZXM&authuser=0

Comment: I failed to reproduce your problem. Visual Studio exits the debugger when I close the window of your application and the Windows Task Manager shows that the process does indeed terminate.
The behavior is the same for both dedicated and integrated graphics. I'm on WIndows 8.1 and GeForce GTX 660M.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving it a shot. This must mean that it's a driver or hardware specific bug. Thank you. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been surfing around a long time to find an answer. The difference between running the application with different Graphics Accelerators is only that the thread doesn't die after WinMain has returned when app is running using dedicated GPU.

To fix this - I found through experimenting that explicitly calling destructors of any live object and then calling std::exit( *return code* ) right before WinMain's return call will kill all threads correctly. It is still weird that the different hardware produces different behavior, though. This solution works for both.

```
**Example**:
WinMain(...){
.
.
.
object.~Class();
std::exit( return-code );
//return return-code;
}
```

I don't like this answer, because it should not be necessary.

Please make sure You add solutions if You have found another way. Thank you in advance.

Most Sincerely,
Alpha Silverback